Best WYSIWYG Editor for document generation and editing (To integrate in Laravel Backpack or Laravel/Inertia/React)
We're currently building a CRM with my company and have trouble choosing between the different WYSIWYG libraries for document generation and editing
For the time being, I've selected CKEditor, TinyMCE, TipTap and Froala, and I'd like to hear your views on how easy they are to set up and use, their price and the extent of customization for each of them.
Thank you
